# doctrine fetch single row large number of rows

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, symfony

i have a table contain 30000+ rows.

(am using symfony3 and doctrine by the way)

and i have this code to get the required post:

```
public function getpost($slug)
    {
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
        'SELECT a FROM BlogBundle:Posts a
        WHERE a.postslug = :slug'
    )->setParameter('slug', $slug);

try {
    return $query->setMaxResults(1)->getOneOrNullResult();
} catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
    return null;
}
```

i noticed that if the post is older and id of post is small, the query time is quicker.

for example showing a post using $slug with id 35, query time is 1ms or even 0ms,
however a post with id of 16000, the query time is 300+ms.

is there any thing to increase the performance?

Comment: is postslug column indexed ?

Comment: it is exister, how else i get the result!. sorry, yes it is indexed

Comment: @SomanDubey asks if you created mysql `index` for column `slug`. This not done by default when table is generated by `Symfony`.  You will get results even if there is no index created on that column.

Comment: Show us your table schema (from mysql) and Entity.

Comment: or look for indexes in mysql client (whichever you're using) if there's none try creating one on postslug.

Comment: thx, i feel dumb, i have index in the posts.orm.yml, but forgot to update the schema. thank you